# How to disable updated_at and created_at when saving data in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, model

I have tried to save data in the model function. When using save() function of the model, I see some error such as below.

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'updated_at' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `account_types` (`name`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (manufactuer, 2019-08-05 05:33:57, 2019-08-05 05:33:57)) in file F:\HTML&

I have deleted created_at and updated_at columns in the table coz I don't need it.
I want to know how I can disable created_at and update_at data saving when using model save() function in the Laravel.

```
<?php

namespace pshub;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class AccountType extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['name'];

    // Create Type Function
    public function createType($type) {
        $existence = $this->where('name', $type)->get();

        if (sizeof($existence) > 0) {
            return $this->where('name', $type);
        } else {
            $this->name = $type;
            $this->save();
            return $this->id;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Just add this:

```
public $timestamps = false;
```

In your model and you are good to go.

Comment: Thank you for good support. Hope to more cooperation with you.

Comment: With this can i go ahead and delete the $table->timestamps() in the migrations? Or do i leave them even after applying your answer

Comment: The reason why to add this to the model is in case you don't have `timestamps` in your table. So yeah, you can delete them since your model won't use them. But if you need them, just leave them as they are, but having `timestamps = false` will avoid updating them.

Comment: So, important, yet absent from beginners' laravel documentation. hmmm...